# opencv rewrite a compressed video file

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, video-processing, video-encoding

Heylo!

I have a video file (unknown compression) of about 500MB in size. I am experimenting with OpenCv and try to discard some frames and resave that file.

When run the program for ~3 minutes (the original file lasts for ~1h) i already have 700MB file :(

How can I maintain the original file size and just discard some frames?

Thx!!!

ps: i am trying to get the original codec using this code:

```
int ex = static_cast<int>(inputVideo.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FOURCC));
```

but apparently ex = 0 ??

Comment: You're definitely going to have to find out what the original codec is in order to produce output in that format. n.b. modern codecs that compare consecutive frames to each other might not work well with frame-skipped input.

Comment: If this question has been successfully answered, consider selecting the official answer by clicking on the checkbox near it. If not, consider adding your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenCV doesn't support all types of containers/codecs, for instance MKV is not supported. [This page](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/VideoCodecs) has an interesting info on the subject.

And [this list](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/documentation/cpp/highgui/VideoWriter) shares some of the FourCC codes that are currently supported.